# check list of email addresses against other list

Tags: string, bash

I have two files with email addresses (one per line): file1 and file2.

How can I remove all the emails in file1 which also exist in file2? Looking for a bash answer, but any other scripting language is fine as well.

If it helps, in each file are only unique email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join -v1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This tells `join` to print the lines (emails) in file1 that do not appear in file2. They have to be sorted, whence the `<(sort ...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow my bash is complaining about unexpected '(', but if I sort the files beforehand and leave out the '<' it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you must preserve the order for whatever reason and want to be overly complicated by contemplating case sensitiveness and carriage returns (^M) you can try:

```
perl -e '%e=();while(<>){s/[\r\n]//g;$e{lc($_)}=1}open($so,"<","file1");while(<$so>){s/[\r\n]//g;print "$_\n" if(!exists($e{lc($_)}))}close($so)' file2
```